# How to apply multiple range filters to a numpy array efficiently?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, sorting, python-itertools

I am modeling a physical problem with thousands of objects where each has coordinates x, y and z. I want to identify the ones which are within some x-distance, y-distance and z-distance of a specific point in space.

One way to do this is as follows:

```
# these are all the coordinates of my thousands of objects
# this can be put into one big array or any other data type earlier if necessary
xpositions = np.array([0.5, -17, 3...])
ypositions = np.array([3, 2, 0,...])
zpositions = np.array([17.5, -8, -1...])

# this is a point in space I am interested in and a small volume around it
x, y, z = -16.5, 0.2, -6
dx, dy, dz = 0.6, 0.5, 3.1

# lets get boolean masks for the objects which fall within this volume around x, y, z
rightx = (abs(xpositions-x)<dx)
righty = (abs(ypositions-y)<dy)
rightz = (abs(zpositions-z)<dz)

# hence the coordinates of the closeby objects
xpositions[rightx*righty*rightz]
ypositions[rightx*righty*rightz]
zpositions[rightx*righty*rightz]
```

This way I have to compare **every coordinate of every object** with those of my point of interest even though in most cases only a tiny fraction will lie in the desired volume. Is there an algorithm or a function possibly in `numpy` or `intertools` which can do this more efficiently - possibly with some clever **sorting**?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/28207/178784

Comment: Logical tests are faster than regular multiplications. Use ```np.logical_and(rightx, np.logical_and(righty, rightz))``` to build your logical indices

Comment: Also avoid make 3 logical indexing operations where you can reduce it to 1: Merge ```xpositions```, ```ypositions``` and ```zpositions``` to a 2D array and do logical indexing once on that array